# Rails generate records for secondary model on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am making a sort of checklist section for my site. I have a model called commission that will contain data about a commissioning task. What I need to do is when a new commission entry is created I need to create a series of about 30 commission tasks that will link to it. A sort of checklist of predefined values for a person to go down through and check. What would be the best way to do this?

Here are my models and controller:

commission.rb

```
    class Commission < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :comtasks
      belongs_to :project
      belongs_to :user
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :comtasks, allow_destroy: true
    end
```

comtask.rb

```
    class Comtask < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :commission
      belongs_to :user
    end
```

commissions_controller.rb

```
    class CommissionsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_commission, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
      # GET /commissions
      # GET /commissions.json
      def index
        @commissions = Commission.all
      end

      # GET /commissions/1
      # GET /commissions/1.json
      def show
      end

      # GET /commissions/new
      def new
        @commission = Commission.new
      end

      # GET /commissions/1/edit
      def edit
      end

      # POST /commissions
      # POST /commissions.json
      def create
        @commission = Commission.new(commission_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @commission.save
            format.html { redirect_to @commission, notice: 'Commission was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @commission }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @commission.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # PATCH/PUT /commissions/1
      # PATCH/PUT /commissions/1.json
      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @commission.update(commission_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @commission, notice: 'Commission was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @commission }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @commission.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # DELETE /commissions/1
      # DELETE /commissions/1.json
      def destroy
        @commission.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to commissions_url, notice: 'Commission was successfully destroyed.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_commission
          @commission = Commission.find(params[:id])
        end


        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def commission_params
          params.require(:commission).permit(:project_id, :user_id, :description, :objectname, :location, comtasks_attributes: [:id, :content, :notes])
        end
    end
```

Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is the idea,

```
def create
  @commission = Commission.create!(commission_params)
  # use create not new to generate @commission.id value
  # so comtask records can use the id value as reference
  create_comtasks_job
  # for comtask create I put in other method
  respond_to do |format|
    if @commission.save

      format.html { redirect_to @commission, notice: 'Commission was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @commission }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @commission.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def create_comtasks_job
  # loop 30 tasks / or manual as follow
  @commission.comtasks.build(content: 'content1',notes:'notes1')
  @commission.comtasks.build(content: 'content2',notes:'notes2')
end
```

#### additional code for your model

make sure for your model has relation like sample below

for your model

```
  class Commission < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comtasks
  end

  class Comtask < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :commission
  end
```

Comment: Thank you. When hooking this up I get this error: undefined method `build' for #<Commission:0x597cf78>

Comment: sorry I had typo for @commission.build previously, I just edited

Comment: Heh I did catch that before. I am still getting the same error. My models do have your edit above. They are listed in my post.

Comment: sorry I just edited again, here is the correct one @ commission.comtasks.build not @ commission.build

Comment: Awesome it works now! Thanks a lot. I appreciate it.